# JS: Should I use a switch-case statement or an if/else for this kind of situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video, switch-statement

I'm trying to minimize (make it more efficient) my JavaScript codes and debating which method I should approach.

I have 10+ pages where each page has two different videos; a short video shown for non-logged-in user and long video shown for logged-in user. I'm working on a WordPress website so I'm targeting each video using the post-id instead of the video player id(plugin) because it is dynamic (changes every time the page refresh). Each video on the page is wrapped in a class so I can target when either video has been clicked.

For example,

```
$f('#post-1883 .short-video .player').bind({
    ready : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('short video'); 
        // Do something here if it's a short video      
    }   
});

 $f('#post-1883 .long-video .player').bind({
    ready : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('long video');
        // Do something here if it's a long video           
    }   
});
```

As you can see in the example, it can be repetitive and clunky when you are targeting 10 videos in the JavaScript file with different post-ID (e.g. #post-1122, #post-4234, and so on).

What would be the best way to approach this situation? Should I use a switch-case statement?

Thanks,
rolu

Comment: Why do you even care about the specific post id's.  Cant you just use the classnames alone?

Comment: Bummer, I'm making this too hard on myself. >.<. You're exactly right, why do I even care about the post id's. I shouldn't. Resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Is this works for you?

```
$('.player').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        videoId = this.id;

    if(self.hasClass('long-video')) {
        console.log('long video');
    } else if(self.hasClass('short-video')) {
        console.log('short-video');
        console.log(videoId);
    }
});
```

You can see the example working on: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmYCj/)